# Javascript in PDFs

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am currently creating a PDF document which has fields on it which I'd like to post into an aspx page.  Now this bit I have working successfully using a button with the added behaviour 'Submit Form'.  I want to tweak this so before the form is submitted a confirmation message pops up, clicking no will abort the for submit, clicking yes will submit the form.

I figure I need to do this in javascript so I've been digging around and come up with the following;

```
var answer = app.alert("Are you ready to submit this form now?", 2, 2, "Confirmation");
if(answer!=4) 
  this.submitForm("http://localhost:8018/quote/apply.aspx");
```

I think my submitForm function is rubbish.  How can I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, I was being dense.  The answer was staring me right in the face.

The first IF block doesn't have the 'THEN' keyword.

Somehow this got past the syntax checker.

The answer is;

```
var answer = app.alert("Are you ready to submit this form now?", 2, 2, "Confirmation");
if(answer==4) 
this.submitForm("http://localhost:8018/quote/apply.aspx");
```

Comment: Wow I feel sheepish... I guess I shouldn't have edited the code as I posted it...